# Unable to persist a transient object with composite key

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a `Hibernate(3.3)` entity `Basket`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASKETS")
@IdClass(BasketId.class)
public class Basket {

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_order", referencedColumnName = "id_o")
    private Order id_order;

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_item", referencedColumnName = "id_i")
    private Item id_item;

    private int amount;

    public Basket() {}

    // generated getters and setters
}
```

with the `BasketId` as is:

```
@Embeddable
public class BasketId implements Serializable {

    private int id_order;
    private int id_item;

    public BasketId() {}

    public BasketId(Order o, Item i) {
        id_order = o.getId_o();
        id_item = i.getId_i();
    }

    // public BasketId(int id_order, int id_item) {
    // this.id_item = id_item;
    // this.id_order = id_order;
    // }

    //generated getter and setters
}
```

The problem is when I want to save a transient `Order` with autowired `SessionFactory session` as `session().save(o)`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_o")
    private int id_o;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private Timestamp date;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_order")
    private Set<Basket> basketItems;

    public Order() {}
    //generated getter and setters
}
```

I get the foolowing exception:

```
message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of foo.server.hib.BasketId.id_item

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of foo.server.hib.BasketId.id_item
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)

root cause

    org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not set a field value by reflection setter of foo.server.hib.BasketId.id_item
    org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectSetter.set(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:114)
    org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:104)
...
root cause

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field foo.server.hib.BasketId.id_item to foo.server.hib.Item
    sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
...
```

The item in the stacktrace is:

```
public class Item {
    //other fields
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_item")
    private Set<Basket> basketsWithThisItem;

    public Item() {}
    //generated getter and setters
}
```

---

I tried with different constructors of `BasketId` (as `(Item, Order)`, and `(int,int)`) as show above, and added `Object` constructors to `Basket`. Next was doing a `merge()` instead of `save()` but nothing helps.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Getters and Setters are there. I use the create function implemented as:

```
@Transactional
public class HibOrderService implements OrderService {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Session session() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }    

    @Override
    public void create(Order o) {
        session().merge(o);
    }

}
```

Comment: can u show me the code for saving

Comment: The code is there @PSR. I added it in the edit, but it was already given in the post between BasketId and Order.

Answer (score 0):

The error exist here

```
Can not set int field foo.server.hib.BasketId.id_item to foo.server.hib.Item




 public BasketId(Order o, Item i) {
        id_order = o.getId_o();
        id_item = i.getId_i();
    }
```

problem here  what  `i.getId_i();` returning

Comment: but you declared  private Item id_item;

Comment: Yes, but in BasketId it's an int.

Comment: @Cornelius see here once http://www.coderanch.com/t/480615/ORM/databases/good-hibernate-composit-key

Comment: while saving you need to save the objects not ids

Answer (score 0):

Add accessors to your @Embeddable class.  get/setId_Order(), get/setId_Item().

Comment: sorry i edited your code instead of my code.Can u please post your code

Comment: @PSR I reverted to the code by Todd Murray, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: They're there, but i forgot to put it in the comments.